# Obter valor de Function no javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Código:

```
    window.onscroll = function (e) {
      console.log(this.oldScroll > this.scrollY)
      this.oldScroll = this.scrollY
    }
```

Como faço para transformar este `console.log` em um return e obter o valor false ou true fora desta function?

observe, eu coloco este trecho dentro de um method que executa quando o componente é criado, ou seja, com a chamada em um created, ele exibe true ou false no console mas nada que tentei me fez obter sucesso em utilizar esta informação para um outro method ou uma var em

`data: () => {}`

claro, se existir uma função nativa para isso, e que seja mais legal, eu aceito a dica, o objetivo é fazer com que duas toolbars distintas desçan ou subam ao rolar o well

Answer (score 2):

A melhor maneira é criar uma propriedade computada:

```
computed: {
  newScrool () {
      return this.oldScroll > this.scrollY
  }
}
```

Para usar em outro método basta `this.newScrool`

Na página: `{{newScrool}}`

Leia mais na documentação oficial do Vue: [Dados Computados](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Dados-Computados)

Comment: bom, isso eu sei fazer, porém, como a informação pode sair do escopo window.onscroll = function (e) { /*sair daqui*/ }

Comment: @flourigh pelo que entendi a melhor maneira é você ter uma variável computada. Seta no ciclo de vida as variáveis `oldScroll e  this.scrollY` e adiciona o código da minha resposta.

Comment: entendo, logo não existe como tirar a informação ali de dentro do scopo?

Answer (score 0):

Ja que você esta criando um *listener* para a ação *scroll* da janela você pode armazenar essa informação em alguma variável em `data`.

```js
let vue = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      oldScroll: 0,
      scrollUP: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleScroll(e) {
      if (this.oldScroll > window.scrollY) {
        this.scrollUP = true
      } else {
        this.scrollUP = false
      }
      this.oldScroll = window.scrollY
    }
  },
  created() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" style="height:900px; padding-top:200px">
  Rolando para cima? {{scrollUP}}
</div>
```

Comment: realmente, concordo que poderia fazer este tipo, o problema é que terei que fazer mais variaveis na data, este exemplo que mostrei não me pede para criar outras vars, não tem como retirar um return dali de dentro?

Comment: Não tem como ter um retorno por ser um event listener. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33501696/how-to-return-value-from-addeventlistener

Comment: entendi, como é um event listener seu return não existe, obrigado

Answer (score -1):

você poderia fazer algo assim:

```
data: () => ({ scroll: 0 }),
created() {
      this.scroll = this.oldScroll > this.scrollY
      // ou this.store.dispatch ...
    }
}
```